# Sign multiple transactions at once by initializing an AccountLoader account in the first transaction and using this initialized account in the 2nd tx

Tags: solana-program, transactions, signature, signing, multisig

I need to sign two transactions at once. The first one initialize an `AccountLoader`, and the second one uses this initialized `AccountLoader`, therefore the `AccountLoader` must be initialized once is called the second transaction. I'm using the following code in the client side:

```
        let allTransactions: Transaction[] = [];
        const tx1 = new Transaction();
        tx1.add(program1.instruction.initializeAccount(
            {
                accounts: {
                    user: userAddress,
                    account: accountAddress, // AccountLoader<'info,zero_copy_account>
                    systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                },
                signers: []
            }
        ));
        allTransactions.push(tx1);

        const tx2 = new Transaction();
        tx2.add(program2.instruction.useAccount(
            {
                accounts: {
                    user: userAddress,
                    account: accountAddress,
                },
                signers: []
            }
        ));
        allTransactions.push(tx2);

        if (wallet.signAllTransactions) {
            const block = await solConnection.getLatestBlockhash();
            allTransactions.forEach(tx => {
                tx.recentBlockhash = block.blockhash;
                tx.feePayer = wallet.publicKey!;
            });

            const signedTransactions = await wallet.signAllTransactions(allTransactions);

            for (const tx of signedTransactions) {
                const txid = await solConnection.sendRawTransaction(
                    tx.serialize(),
                    {
                        skipPreflight: false,
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

When I run this code the first transaction is completed successfully, however the second one fails. I think this is because the account is not initialized when the second transaction is being executed.

When I run the @Jon C example both transactions fail. However, if I run the @Jon C example using an `account` of type `Account` (not `AccountLoader`) both transactions are executed successfully. Why does this approach fail when using `AccountLoader`?

Does anyone know how to complete these two transactions using a single sign?

Comment: Could you include the error that you're seeing?

Comment: `Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xbc4` Where can I find the description of this error?

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, sending two transactions at once that have some dependent state is extremely error-prone, since you can't guarantee the order in which the leader will process the transactions.

If you want to do two things at once, the best option is to do everything in one transaction, ie:

```
        const tx1 = new Transaction();
        tx1.add(program1.instruction.initializeAccount(
            {
                accounts: {
                    user: userAddress,
                    account: accountAddress, // #[account(init,...
                    systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                },
                signers: []
            }
        ));
        tx1.add(program2.instruction.useAccount(
            {
                accounts: {
                    user: userAddress,
                    account: accountAddress,
                },
                signers: []
            }
        ));
```

If that isn't possible due to transaction size or compute limit, then you have to send the first transaction, wait for it to confirm, then send the second transaction. I think you'll be able to do the first method in this case though.

Comment: You are right, it is extremely error prone. It has also happened to me that one transaction completes successfully while the other fails and I can't allow that. Do you know if there is a way to specify the order? What you say about doing a transaction first and then checking for success is not possible for me since I have to do it both transactions with a single wallet signature.

Comment: In my example of adding two instructions to one transaction, they are guaranteed to be executed in that order, so definitely go with that approach

Comment: Your example works perfectly if the account that needs to be initialized (`account`) is of `Account` type. However, your example doesn't work if the account to be initialized is of `AccountLoader` type, which is my case.